# How to draw TGPGraphics contents onto a Canvas

Tags: delphi, canvas, gdi+

I'm trying to copy the contents of the following TGPGraphics onto a Canvas but it doesn't work. What am I missing here?

```
function DrawGlyph(bm: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas; X, Y: Integer): Integer;
var
  O: TGPBitmap;
  G: TGPGraphics;
begin
  if (bm is TGPImage) then
  begin
    O := TGPBitmap.Create(16, 16, PixelFormat32bppARGB);
    try
      G := TGPGraphics.Create(O);
      try
        G.SetCompositingMode(CompositingModeSourceCopy);
        G.SetInterpolationMode(InterpolationModeHighQualityBicubic);
        G.SetPixelOffsetMode(PixelOffsetModeHighQuality);
        G.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeHighQuality);
        G.DrawImage(TGPImage(bm), 0, 0, O.GetWidth, O.GetHeight);

        BitBlt(Canvas.Handle, X, Y, O.GetWidth, O.GetHeight, G.GetHDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
      finally
        G.Free;
      end;

    finally
      O.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Why do you want to use intermediate TGPBitmap? If you change it to G:= TGPGraphics.Create(Canvas.Handle) then it works

Comment: I also wanted to resize the image to 16x16 before drawing it onto a Canvas

Comment: It resizes even if you draw directly to canvas

Comment: How do I directly draw to canvas?

Comment: As I said in first comment replace line G := TGPGraphics.Create(O) with G := TGPGraphics.Create(Canvas.Handle), in this case image is drawn resized on canvas. Does it not work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw the `TGPGraphics` onto the Canvas directly with the constructor

```
TGPGraphics.Create(hdc: HDC)
```

You also do not need the `O: TGPBitmap` e.g.:

```
function DrawGlyph(bm: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas; X, Y: Integer): Integer;
var
  G: TGPGraphics;
begin
  // Result := ???
  if (bm is TGPImage) then
  begin
    Canvas.Lock;
    try
      G := TGPGraphics.Create(Canvas.Handle);
      try
        G.SetCompositingMode(CompositingModeSourceCopy);
        G.SetInterpolationMode(InterpolationModeHighQualityBicubic);
        G.SetPixelOffsetMode(PixelOffsetModeHighQuality);
        G.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeHighQuality);
        G.DrawImage(TGPImage(bm), X, Y, 16, 16);
      finally
        G.Free;
      end;
    finally
      Canvas.Unlock;
    end;
  end;
end;
```